# Is there a way to set/change proxy in synaptic package manager from terminal?

Tags: command-line, proxy, synaptic

I want to change proxy settings of Synaptic package manager from terminal. I see that editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file does not work, i.e., even if I change proxy settings here, or anywhere, Synaptic Package manager won't use it.

Basically, I dont want to go everytime inside the settings of SPM to change the proxy. I want to make a small script which will do this job.

Does anyone know in which file are the proxy credentials of Synaptic Package Manager (SPM) is stored?

Comment: Other method would be Open synaptic as root , by `gksu synaptic` and set the proxy setting . Then try running it as normal , and see if it has retained the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored in the /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf file,  you can see an example in the following script

http://ubuntuone.com/4PXwbNWmNj5kK9AUkEb9fF

Have fun :)

Comment: Wow, exactly the thing I was looking for.
Take a bow man, you are just awesome :)

Comment: Always put the important parts of the example in your answer since the files you link to are not guaranteed to last forever, which severely reduces the usefulness of your answer.